# iCloud KeyValueStore preference changes and handling them across various devices

Tags: ios, icloud

As per Apple's guidelines my app provides an option for user to enable/disable storage in iCloud.

Use case :

- By default the storage in iCloud is disabled
- User downloads the app on iOS Device 1 and creates some files etc
- User then downloads the app on iOS Device 2 and create some files etc. These files are different from those created on iOS Device 1
- User then enables iCloud on iOS Device 1. This setting is propagated to iOS Device 2 using KV store of iCloud. Also the files in iOS Device 1 sandbox are moved to iCloud

Scenario 1:

User starts the app on iOS Device 2. I know that now iCloud is enabled and I prompt the user that it was enabled on some other device and I am moving your local files to iCloud. I think there is no problem here.

Scenario 2:

When the notification arrived (that iCloud is enabled on device 1) user was using the app on iOS Device 2 and had few modal views on the screen. I am not sure how to inform the user about the change and perform the operation i.e move device 2's sandbox files to iCloud.

Should all the viewcontrollers of the app have the capability to be interrupted and handle this event ?

Looking for some suggestions and guidance here on the user experience and right thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

Save the a device-specific setting in NSUserDefaults and don't upload files automatically — it seems a little wrong to automatically upload things because a setting changed on another device. If you force the user to navigate to an "Enable iCloud Storage" view controller, you have much more control over what other VCs are visible and are less likely to run into surprises.

It could also be worthwhile making it a per-file setting (e.g. perhaps files they don't want in iCloud for security/space reasons).

Alternatively, a UIAlertView should work from anywhere in your app, but you'll have to make sure that files can be shifted to iCloud seamlessly while they're being viewed (and edited?) in a view controller.